# What is the reason for occurence of introns in eukaryotic mRNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, transcription, mrna

After transcription of the Template strand of DNA, in prokaryotes, the translation process begins immediately. But in eukaryotes the mRNA transcript has both non coding (introns) as well as coding (exons) sequences. So they undergo Post Transcriptional processes i.e. Splicing, Capping and Tailing.

From where do non-coding sequences arise in eukaryotic mRNA? I'm guessing its from Heterochromatin (found only in eukaryotes). Is this correct?

Also the process in prokaryotes seems to be hassle-free and simultaneous. But what is the reason for such a complicated process in the *more evolved* eukaryotes?

Comment: No organism is *more evolved* than any other. That aside, no one knows why introns exist, but we do know that they presently play roles in gene regulation and generating protein isoforms

Comment: Please note that you are required to some research of your own before posting here. Not only could you have searched this site to find that your question has been posted before, but you could have searched Wikipedia or the web in general. I see you have not completed the guided tour as you lack the corresponding badge. Please do so if you intend to use this site.

Comment: @David My apologies sir for not having done my homework. I wasn't duplicating anyone else's work. Its a genuine thought and i was too overwhelmed by it and posted it immediately. I could have done everything you said. I regret it.

Comment: No big deal, just explaining how the site operates. Nobody is accusing you of duplicating anyone's work — that's a standard message generated by the system.

Comment: Oh thank you so much sir. I'm totally free of the burden of an accusation:)